# In Excel VBA get an Error 1004 whilst running a loop in real time, it works fine when I skip through line by line using debugger

Tags: excel, for-loop

I made some code to loop backwards through some records eliminating records where a string concatenating values from several fields indicated duplicate value existing.  It battered my head building the thing but it seemed to work fine when I ran it earlier and also no problems when I stepped through the macro using the debugger but now it won't run properly and I don't understand why.  It gives an error 1004 - Application-defined or Object defined error at the point where I concatenate the contents of several cells to make a string.

I wondered if it might be a system-resource kind of problem but really don't understand how that could be.

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates(Endrow)
' A sub to remove data where Species, Location (Lat and Long) and accuracy are all the same and to return the most recent year
' whilst ignoring older records.
' This leaves the lowest row number of a set of duplicates since the sheet has been sorted by the previous function to put
' The highest date on the lowest row number.


Endrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
EndCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

Dim iString As String
Dim iPlusString As String
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveSheet
For i = Endrow To 2 Step -1
Startloop:
iString = .Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value & .Cells(i, 3).Value & .Cells(i, 12).Value
iPlusString = .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value & .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value & .Cells(i + 1, 3).Value & .Cells(i + 1, 12).Value

'This was just to watch where the data was to make things easier.
'Rows(i).Select

    If i = Endrow Then
    i = i - 1
    GoTo Startloop
    Else
        If Stringi = iPlusString Then
        Rows(i + 1).Delete
        Else
        i = i - 1
        GoTo Startloop
        End If
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Stringi and istring should be the same - I tried changing it round in case the error was down to using some reserved word I hadn't encountered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using the `RemoveDuplicates` method of the `Range` object would be simpler.

Without your data to test on, something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim endRow As Long, endCol As Long, dtCol As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet3")
With WS
    endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    endCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rg = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
    dtCol = rg.Rows(1).Find(what:="Date").Column
End With

'Optional to Sort with most recent date first, if not already sorted this way
rg.Sort key1:=rg.Columns(dtCol), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

'remove duplicates
rg.RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2, 3, 12), xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a really short tidy piece of code!  Thanks very much for your help.  I see your code uses an array.  I'm new to arrays and have just found that some code I wrote with nested loops was unbearably slow so I'm of to learn how to use them now.  (Wise Owl Tutorials on youtube has been most helpful).  Thanks again - I'll try and implement this when I understand it a bit better!

Comment: Hi there, I tried your code, it works like a dream and there are approaches in here I had absolutely no idea about like your removing duplicates like that and the concise way you sorted everything.  Certainly beats all the flapping about I did with backward looping nested loops. Thank you so much; it's an education as well as a solution! :)